# Detecting recurring transactions from history

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, finance

I'm hoping someone could lead me in the right direction. I have a list of users and money transactions for a service.

The data I have: userid, transaction date, transaction amount. Based on those three variables, is it possible that for a new transaction I could code something where it can decide/provide probability that the new transaction is likely recurring.

Example would be a user has a transaction for $100 at the end of the month, every month. If a new transaction for the same amount comes in the next month it's a high probability it's reoccuring, as opposed to a 25 dollar transaction towards the start of the month

or someone has had a transaction for around 1200 in December the last 10 years. If they do that again this year it's likely recurring.

Any help for guidance as to how to tackle this or machine learning models to use.

Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could do a frequency transform (FFT) or use autocorrelation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) to find the "periodic signal" if any.

Comment: Your question is too general, you will have to define your limits on what is recurring and what isn't and then look for tools. Even then, you may have to try implement one of them and put a question here if the problem arises. "code something", "what model to use" these phrases may indicate lack of clarity.

Comment: Hello did you manage to find any solution on this?